How To register FluentValidation from multiple assemblies
How can i add fluentvalidation which have validation in multiple assemblies.
I have validators also in a shared class Library:
    public class TestModelValidator : AbstractValidator<TestModel>
    {
      rules...
    }

    public class TestModel2Validator : AbstractValidator<TestModel2>
    {
      rules...
    }
...
    public class TestMode999Validator : AbstractValidator<TestMode999>
    {
      rules...
    }
in my startup.cs:
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();
        services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
        services.AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters();


Install package FluentValidation.AspNetCore
Then you can use extension method like this:
 services.AddFluentValidation(fv =>
        {
                fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Assembly1Class>();
            fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Assembly2Class>();
        });

Or you can use method fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblies() and pass list of  assemblies.

Tnx Memisevic, It works.
